# Using regex function to manipulate string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, jsessionid

I would like to remove `jsessionid=99171C97AE28712E048E321DB6B192F3` from the string below using regex in c#

```
www.ploscompbiol.org/article/fetchObjectAttachment.action;jsessionid=99171C97AE28712E048E321DB6B192F3?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0066655&representation=XML
```

I have tried

```
string id = id.Replace(";jsessionid=.*?(?=\\?|$)", "");
```

but it is not working, please help!

Comment: That's `string.Replace`, not `Regex.Replace`. Also, there's no way I'm downloading a file from a site I don't know. Post the actual XML.

Comment: I do not thinking posting the actual XML would make any difference. I only need to stop `jsessionid` from appending to the url or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(text, "jsessionid=[^\\?]+","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to remove the jsession.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("jsessionid=[^\\?]*)");
string id = rgx.Replace(line,"");
```

Comment: string.Replace is not working and surfing through this site, some suggested string.replaceAll, which i cant find.

Comment: They might have been talking about Java which has a `replaceAll` method.  For this just use the regex replace

Answer (score 0):

In case you change your mind and you don't want to use RegEx but manage with string.replace function,

```
        string sample = "ansjsessionid=99171C97AE28712E048E321DB6B192F3wer";
        sample = sample.Replace( sample.Substring(sample.IndexOf("jsessionid="),43),"");
```

Note that I've assumed that ID is always 32 character long.

Answer (score 0):

Solution not using Regex:

```
var url = @"www.ploscompbiol.org/article/fetchObjectAttachment.action;jsessionid=99171C97AE28712E048E321DB6B192F3?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0066655&representation=XML";

var startIndex = url.IndexOf("jsessionid=");
var endIndex = url.IndexOf('?', startIndex);
url.Remove(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Note if a `'?'` is not found then it will throw an exception.